# what is the command code for 64bit windows electron js?

Tags: electron, desktop-application, hybrid, electron-packager

In Nodejs Package.json i have the below commands for 32bit Windows app:
  **"package-win": "electron-packager . Test -App --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32  --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Test App\"",**

but i want the same for 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 8):

Just replace `--arch=ia32` to `--arch=x64`.

"platform" stays "win32", it's all right.

Comment: Do you know why when using --asar=true we get the following warning:  

WARNING: --asar does not take any arguments, it only has sub-properties (see --help)